# Fire requests outside the pipeline using netty.io

Tags: java, netty, pipelining

What is the correct way to implement using netty a proxy, but just in a stage in the pipeline
For example
`

```
@Override
  public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();

        ChannelBuffer time = ChannelBuffers.buffer(4);
      time.writeInt((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L + 2208988800L));

      ChannelFuture f = ch.write(time);

     f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
              Channel ch = future.getChannel();
                ch.close();
          }
        });
  }`
```

Instead of obtaining the current Date using the currentTimeMillis API,
fire an async request to another server, get the result, and proceed with the next step of the pipeline.
Thanks in advance